# Pdf generation in Asp.net mvc with NReco.PdfGenerator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, nreco

Im new in NReco.PdfGenerator.We have partial view and it's carrying html tags what we need.

In our partial view html:

```
<img src="https://www.nrecosite.com/img/pdfgenerator/donald_sign.jpg" />
```

We're exporting pdf without this image and get this error:

> Warning: Failed to load
>   https://www.nrecosite.com/img/pdfgenerator/donald_sign.jpg (ignore)

What can I do to solve this problem.

With Respect,

Comment: This error means that you have reference to this image but it cannot be accessed from the server where PDF generation is performed.

Comment: I didnt find any solution about this error , but we're using server file to generate pdf and image is showing. Thanks :)